# How can I select a region in an image file, and hide the region?

Tags: image-processing, pinta

How can I select a region in an image file, and hide or blur the region (e.g. barcode, or personal information) in any way that you think is reasonable?

I have tried pinta. I first select a rectangle region, and then try to use paint bucket to fill the region, but it doesn't fill the region at all, or I don't know 
how.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by hide ? Does it hide completely or kinda blurring it ?

Comment: Since you seem to prefer a solution with pinta, make that clear in the question itself rather than as comments to answers.

Answer (score 5):

Open the image in GIMP. Click **Tools > Selection Tools > Rectangle Select Tool**. Outline the area you wish to blur.

Next, click **Tools > Paint Tools > Smudge**. Use the mouse to smudge the selected area as desired.

Next, click **Select > None**. Next click **File > Export As**... Export the file as any file format you wish. Exit GIMP.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use pinta? I guess so, but I don't know how

Comment: All I can get pinta to do is crash, so I haven't any suggestions.

Comment: thanks, didn't wanted confidential documents to fall into wrong hands by submitting to web editing sites, i need to learn gimp, its amazing.

Answer (score 3):

You can give Shutter a try:

```
sudo apt install shutter
```

If you're using 18.04 or a later version, then you should install the required dependencies in order to edit in Shutter **(Skip if you use 16.04)**:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas-common_1.0.0-1_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoocanvas3_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgoo*.deb
```

Open the Shutter program, take the screenshot or open your image file, then click "Edit", this will bring you to editing process.

To blur, click the **Blur** tools.

[image: screenshot, blur tool on left panel]

Then, you can select a region you want to blur/censor.

[image: rectangular selection blurred]

Save it, and see your result.

[image: screenshot, blurred section]

The result will be saved in the `~/Pictures` directory in your home folder.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use pinta? I guess so, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that also with Pinta: *Effects* → *Blurs* → *Gaussian Blur*.

I've also written a [more detailed tutorial with screenshots](https://blog.nicohood.de/how-to-add-a-blur-effect-to-images-with-pinta) on my blog. Also [checkout the official Pinta docs](https://www.pinta-project.com/user-guide/effects/#gaussian).

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, up to date, opened a simple PNG, selected an area and app crashed immediately. Tried twice, crashed twice!

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 ships Pinta 1.6 which is quite outdated. You might want to try the official PPA: https://launchpad.net/~pinta-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/pinta-stable Otherwise open a bugreport here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta